# How to get Country name using Location Services in Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my `Application`, i'm using `Payment Gateway`. Based on the `User Country` i have to change `Payment method type`. By using `Locale` i can get Country but it gives `Device Configured/Manufactured` country which is not useful for me.So i am trying `Google Play Services (Location Services)`. How can i get only `Country name` by using this `API`. I don't want Latitude Longitude etc. Thanks

Comment: If all you need is Country of the user, why not get the Country of the current SIM card?

Comment: that is one possible option. If user using Tablet How can i get?

Answer (score 3):

If the device is a phone, then you can get the country this way.

```
 public static String getUserCountry(Context context) {
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String simCountry = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        if (simCountry != null && simCountry.length() == 2) { // SIM country code is available
            return simCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) { // device is not 3G (would be unreliable)
            String networkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
            if (networkCountry != null && networkCountry.length() == 2) { // network country code is available
                return networkCountry.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return null;
}
```

and then , can access it:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("", getUserCountry(this));

TextView.setText(loc.getDisplayCountry());
```

**PS**:
you'll need to add the permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: Thanks For this code. Let me try.. Do i need add Any Permissions for this.

Comment: glad it did help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Current Place Api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place) for this.

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
     for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
         Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
         placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
         placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
     }

     likelyPlaces.release();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks foe Suggestion. Let me try your Code. Any Permissions to add?